# How can i restart saved scheduler in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, apscheduler

With following codes, i saved jobstore in my `mysql` Database for testing.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler

def tick ():
    print ("Hi")

sched = BlockingScheduler()
url = 'mysql://myname:mypw@localhost/rssdb'
sched.add_jobstore('sqlalchemy', url=url)
sched.add_job(tick,'interval',seconds=10)
sched.start()
```

I have checked it was saved properly and want to load and execute the job.
how should i do ?

Comment: Every scheduler has a concept of 'workers'. A worker is a program which does the actual task of calling the function when the scheduled time is hit.
In case of `apscheduler` workers are called `executors`. You need to create and start your `executors`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the job is saved into mysql and you see that
You can do following. When adding job also include which jobstore you want to add it. Also you can add other options like job_defaults to the Scheduler together with job_stores

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler

def tick ():
   print ("Hi")

jobstores = {
        'sqlalchemy': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='mysql://myname:mypw@localhost/rssdb')
}
sched = BlockingScheduler(jobstores=jobstores)
sched.start()
#to add a job you better also say which jobstore you want to add it
sched.add_job(tick,'interval',seconds=10, jobstore='sqlalchemy')
```